# Make input parameter mandatory JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

Input paramter to my webservice method is an Object of Class AddSingleDocRequest. This class contains all the input fields as class instance variable with their getter and setter. I want to make some of the input fields mandatory. What is the best way to achieve this ?

Following is the code snippet:

```
**//webservice method

public String uploadDoc(AddSingleDocRequest request)
    {
    }

**//Request Class**

public class AddSingleDocRequest 
{

  private String sFilepath;

  private String sDataClass;

  public void setDataClassName(String dataClassName) 
{
        this.sDataClass= dataClassName;
    }


    public String getDataClassName() {
        return sDataClass;
    }

   public void setFilePath(String filePath)
    {
        this.sFilepath=filePath;
    }

    public String getFilePath()
    {
        return sFilepath;
    }
}
```

I want to make sFilePath parameter as mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Add the next JAX-B annotations:

```
@XmlType(name = "AddSingleDocRequestType", propOrder = {
    "sFilepath", "sDataClass"
})
public class AddSingleDocRequest {

    @XmlElement(name = "sFilepath", required = true)
    private String sFilepath;

    @XmlElement(name = "sDataClass", required = false)
    private String sDataClass;

    public void setDataClassName(String dataClassName) {
        this.sDataClass = dataClassName;
    }

    public String getDataClassName() {
        return sDataClass;
    }

    public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
        this.sFilepath = filePath;
    }

    public String getFilePath() {
        return sFilepath;
    }
}
```

See more in [*Using JAXB to customize mapping for JAX-WS web services*](http://www.middlewareguru.com/mw/?p=528).

Comment: But these annotations cannot be resolved. is there any jar to be included in build path for using annotations ?

Comment: Oh! Sorry! Add `import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;`

Comment: Yeah. After importing error is resolved but still in the generated WSDL, minoccurs=0 is there for input fields. In Axis 2 lib direcory on server, jaxb-api-2.1 is present, is 2.2 JAX-B is required or what ?